# Grails : 'methodInvocation' error code when validate domain object

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

Since two weeks, a wild issue appears !
It comes only in production (not in dev, integration, preproduction modes) and after hours....

Symptoms : once "something" happens, users cannot sign up anymore. After days and days of investigations, I have no clue how to reproduce neither where come this issue.
For now, we have the ugly workaround to restart tomcat instances, but this is *VERY* ugly.

For information, differences between two deliveries doesn't touch around the sign up process.

Here what I think is relevant :

Domain :

```
class UserAccount implements Serializable {
    static transients = ['tokenLogin']
    String email
    String pwd
    Date creationDate = new Date()
    String tokenLogin


    //[skip] dozen of other attributes

    static constraints = {
        email(matches:EmailRegexp,blank:false)
        pwd(blank:false)
        tokenLogin(editable:false)
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email
        authId = authenticationChannel.getUsername(email)
        // We must recalculate token login
        this.tokenLogin = generateTokenLogin(email, creationDate, pwd)
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd
        // We must recalculate token login
        this.tokenLogin = generateTokenLogin(email, creationDate, pwd)
    }

    public static String generateTokenLogin(String email, Date creationDate, String pwd) {
        // work well
        // even tested when return null or with NPE in it and does not produce the same log
        generated = // work with MessageDigest, MD5, salt, etc. (not disclosed, because we are currently under security audit)
        return generated;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
def saveAccount = {
    def user = new UserAccount(email: params.email?.trim(), pwd: params.pwd) // More parameters, but here what is relevant
    user.validate()
    if(user.hasErrors()) log.info("${user.errors}") // added since the issue appears
    // Other verification (unicity, clear password verification, etc.)
    // Password encryption
    // user.save()
}
```

Output log :

```
2013-06-03 15:37:32,165 [TP-Processor46] INFO  controller.UserAccountController  - org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'domain.UserAccount' on field 'pwd': rejected value [foobar]; codes [methodInvocation.domain.UserAccount.pwd,methodInvocation.pwd,methodInvocation.java.lang.String,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [domain.UserAccount.pwd,pwd]; arguments []; default message [pwd]]; default message [Property 'pwd' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

Questions :

- How this output might be appears? We saw this ouput either for `pwd` or `email` field, never for others.
- What is the signification of "methodInvocation" code? (I have seen in spring-context that `MethodInvocationException` is thrown when `BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue` catch an exception)
- How to get more information? (Now, we run a patched spring-context.jar displaying the StackTrace in BeanWrapperImpl, but we cannot reproduce until now)

Informations :

- Grails 1.3.7 => spring 3.0.5-GA
- Mysql jdbc
- Tomcat 6

In `start.sh` (tomcat options)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dapp=prod -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled \
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
-Xloggc:/path/to/gc.log"
```

Edit :
We change and compile `spring-context.jar` to be able to see a StackTrace. and we get this one :

```
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'pwd' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1127)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:673)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:569)
        at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:191)
[snip]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.checkCall(PojoMetaClassSite.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at domain.UserAccount.generateTokenLogin(UserAccount.groovy:369)
        at domain.UserAccount$generateTokenLogin.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at domain.UserAccount$generateTokenLogin.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at domain.UserAccount.setPwd(UserAccount.groovy:184)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1114)
```

The root cause is that exists an `creationDate` that might be `null` on some weird conditions. I guess the solution is not to call `generateTokenLogin()` in setters (and only in getters).

I cannot explain why we did not have this issue before (no recent upgrade, etc.)

Comment: Where's your constraints block in UserAccount?

Comment: I keep the order, I didn't think definition order matter, does it ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your constraints seems pretty simple. Since it's an error in the password field, I guess it's related to `generateTokenLogin()`. I suggest you to separate this from the setter, to see if the NullPointer occurs in this method.

Comment: Anything interesting in catalina.out?

Comment: I second @SérgioMichels. Second step after following what Sergio said, will be to make `generateTokenLogin()` non-static.

Comment: `generateTokenLogin()` is a method that exists for years and never touched since '2011-07-29' (git blame). I tried to reproduce the output log as I said in code comments. Output log above is in catalina.out and no stacktrace around about this subject (First, there were no output in this cases, we added output to investigate).
About `static`, if it were the problem, the method should never be called, should it ?

Comment: @Isammoc It was not about validity of method call. It was about the way it is called. static method `generateTokenLogin()` will be present in the heap before the `UserAccount` object is created. I think you would get the same issue with `email` if you set it after setting password.

Comment: @dmahapatro You're right, email get the same issue in some run (it was the reason to show it here). But, why is this beginning after hours and hours ? And as I said, I tried to reproduce (set email and/or pwd to null at the beginning of the `generateTokenLogin()` method) and the issue didn't happen. My extract was not totally accurate about the generateTokenLogin (edit)

Comment: @sergio-michels Please, one of you may write an answer with the fact that generateTokenLogin() should not be called inside a setter. I will edit my question with last informations

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like once this happens it isn't fixed without a restart. I would look at the permgen size for your application. If it works in every environment expect production it might be a memory issues.

Easy way to test is add 200megs or so to start.

Comment: You're right, once it happens, we must restart as a workaround. Options are :  `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`.
Neither OutOfMemoryError in log, nor heap dump file

Comment: I wonder if something doesn't get removed during a permgensweep which isn't being added back correctly... I'm not sure but my hunch is increase permgen a bit and see if it helps.

Comment: Also you aren't deploying to that tomcat in-between it working and it failing are you?

Comment: We never deploy to a running tomcat. (We have two tomcat instances and for deployment light enough, we swap from one to the other).
About increasing pergem, why now ? Why is there no stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess - when you override a setter, you shouldn't set the value of that field inside this setter, because it's a kind of recursion, or at least unpredicted behavior (like this) could be expected, maybe try using raw field access operator:

```
public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this.@pwd = pwd
    // We must recalculate token login
    this.tokenLogin = generateTokenLogin(email, pwd)
}
```

the same goes for `email` field/setter

Comment: Why this issue appears after years in production ? But you're right, we should use `this.@pwd` in this case

Comment: grails version opgrade? I don't know if this is a reason for this particular problem, I just know that something like that may cause very unexpected effects

Comment: No update and only minor modifications for other parts of the application. It's why I dont understand how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Is your pre-prod server exactly the same as your prod server ?
Which are the minors modifications you make, are you sur there is no impact ?

It could be the war generated which contains errors, did you try a rollback on your modifications ?

Mayby you could take your prod war and put it into your pre-prod env to reproduce the issue.

Is there a recent update from a plugin, grails version, or whatever in your dependencies ?

Not answering your question, but peraps I can give you investigations ideas.

Snite

Comment: different machines, but same configuration (hardware + software) on both prod/preprod. Same build process but `-Dgrails.env` value. If it was the generated war that contains errors, why only after an amount of time ? Rollback is no longer an option (DB incompatibility). We can test our prod war. No recent update. Current test : we have recompile spring-context.jar with an `e.printStackTrace()` where the `methodInvocation` output is created. (we expect more information from this). But not reproduce since the modification.

Comment: No idea about your issue, this is very strange.
Here is a tool wich give you intresting information about your server (disk usage, classes loaded, memory usage). You could install it on your server, and when the next crash occur, you could analyse the results, I think it will be helpful. (http://munin-monitoring.org/)